# rabbitmq bash script -f -h meaning

Tags: bash, rabbitmq

In the same rabbitmq's script of "rabbitmq-env", there exists "-h", "-f", in the following lines:

```
while [ -h "$SCRIPT_PATH" ] ; do

[ ! -f ${CONF_ENV_FILE} ] ; then
```

What's the meaning of these symbols?

Comment: You can learn more about Bash syntax from the [reference manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html) or the [man page](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[` is `test`. From `help test`:

```
  -f FILE        True if file exists and is a regular file.
   ...
  -h FILE        True if file is a symbolic link.
```